# Dataframe values are not converting to String properly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having data in excel and reading as below and i am trying to convert all data to string-

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel('excel')
df.fillna('(Null)').astype(str)
```

even though i convert to string using `astype(str)`, but in some case, i get float values as below(67.0) and how do i avoid this keeping just as string '67'-

```
  Name  id
0   A   123
1   B   67.0
2   C   30
3   D   40
4   E   50
```

Comment: How working `df=pd.read_excel('excel', dtype=str)` ?

Comment: Problem `67.0` should be float value in input file, so after converting to string get `67.0` to `'67.0'`

Comment: @jezrael thanks. right now i have only column id, but how do i avoid this problem dynamically[suppose new column coming in the input file].basically all columns in input file convert to string properly. i will try df=pd.read_excel('excel', dtype=str)

Comment: @J_Coder is your problem solved?

Comment: df=pd.read_excel('excel', dtype=str) works fine